Clock feedthrough in 5T OTAs?
I'm using a 5T OTA as a comparator, and the reference voltage is applied to the gate of M2 by another circuit - I modelled it with a capacitor (100fF) charged to Vref, just for describing my question. Also, I saw the same result when replacing the other circuit with this capacitor.
The problem is Vin1 changes pretty fast (50mV/1ns), and on the rising/falling edge of Vin1, the drain and source voltage of M1, and even Vref changes (Vg2). What's the reason behind this? Would a buffer between the two circuits help?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

When VREF drives the gain node (M2), you get feedthrough from the output to the G of M2 as the output toggles.
If you exchange inputs, then VREF only drives a diode-connected M3, and the swing there is smaller, leading to negligible feedthrough.

I think it depends on what the bias current is, the device parameters, etc. Yes, the swing at M3 source is smaller, but it's not zero. I've tried a discrete implementation and the difference between the swing at M3.S and M4.S largely depends on what the overall gain was. Cascoding M1 and M2 would definitely help.

I also noted the voltage M1.S swings, why is this? Is it possible that feedthrough is from M1.S to M2.S then to M2.G?
